# python - how to properly evaluate a value from a system command

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm just learning python (using 2.7.8) and i'm trying to figure out what is the best way to evaluate the output of a system command. I've read to use `subprocess`. 
For example, I need to run this `IF` statment and evaluate for anything `> 0`, then process it.

Example of unix command:
`cat dump_cars_tbl.out | grep -i hummer | wc -l'` (in this case it should return a value of `1`)

In python, I've tested this, but my results is wrong. It should return a `Yes`.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> mycat=subprocess.call('cat dump_cars_tbl.out | grep -i hummer | wc -l', shell=True)
1
>>> if mycat > 0:
...     print('Yes')
... else:
...     print('No')
...
No
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, should i use `subprocess.call` for something like this? I also need to make sure that the command `mycat` doesn't return an error too.

If you have a better example how to execute and evaulate a command like this, please show me. Thank you.

Comment: The result of `subprocess.call` is the *error code*, which should be zero in the case of the process completing successfully. You're probably looking for `subprocess.check_output`, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `subprocess.check_output`:

```
mycat = int(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `shell=True` here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_output

count = int(check_output(['grep', '-ci', 'hummer', 'dump_cars_tbl.out']))
```

You don't need to run an external process, to find the number of lines that contain the substring `hummer` (ignoring-case) in a given file i.e., to emulate `<dump_cars_tbl.out grep -ci hummer` shell command in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
with open('dump_cars_tbl.out', 'rb') as file:
    count = sum(1 for line in file if b'hummer' in line.lower())
```